Supply only payload schema for FastAPI endpoint without actual validation by Pydantic
I need to supply only payload schema for API endpoint without any Pydantic validation. I'm using:

FastAPI==0.110.1
Pydantic v2

from typing import Literal, Annotated
    
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, RootModel

app = FastAPI()


def get_openapi_extra(model) -> dict:
    return {
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {"application/json": {"schema": model.schema(ref_template="#/components/schemas/{model}")}}
        }
    }


class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog']
    barks: float


class Lizard(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['reptile', 'lizard']
    scales: bool


class Model(RootModel):
    root: Annotated[Cat | Dog | Lizard, Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')]


@app.get("/", openapi_extra=get_openapi_extra(Model))
def index():
    return "ok"

When I was using Pydantic v1 and FastAPI==0.98.0 it worked without problems. But when I started to upgrade to Pydantic v2 and FastAPI 0.110.1 I started facing the next problem:

It seems that FastAPI does not know about Lizard, Dog and Cat schemas...
How to fix it?

Does it work as you expect with actual requests with for example curl? (i.e. can this be a change related to swagger and not Pydantic/FastAPI core?)

The way the errors are present in the OpenAPI docs page aren't very helpful, however they do tell you what's wrong: the doc rendering logic can't resolve a reference somewhere in the schema.
The model schemas you're trying to reference using the openapi_extra parameter need to exist in FastAPI's OpenAPI schema cache at startup as far as I can tell, under components/schemas/{model_name}.
I can't share the code I've written for this as-is, but when I get a moment I'll try to make a proper post with a full solution. Hope this helps for now!

I think for your case need to use model_json_schema instead of schema, need to do this
from typing import Literal, Annotated
    
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, RootModel

app = FastAPI()


def get_openapi_extra(model) -> dict:
    return {
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {"application/json": {"schema": model. model_json_schema(ref_template="#/components/schemas/{model}")}}
        }
    }


class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog']
    barks: float


class Lizard(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['reptile', 'lizard']
    scales: bool


class Model(RootModel):
    root: Annotated[Cat | Dog | Lizard, Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')]


@app.get("/", openapi_extra=get_openapi_extra(Model))
def index():
    return "ok"

This is stated here https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types

Errors still remains
